# how to write criteria builder API JPA query for below statement

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql, openjpa

I have two tables Employee and Department. I want to write Criteria buider API JPA query for the below statement.

SELECT * FROM Employee e

WHERE emp_name IN

(SELECT emp_name
FROM Department d
WHERE d.emp_parentName IN('Ross','shane'))

ORDER BY e.emp_name

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a criteriaQuery without join, using a subquery:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManger.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> baseRoot = query.from(Employee.class);

Subquery<Department> subquery = query.subquery(Department.class);
Root<Department> subroot = subquery.from(Department.class);
subquery.select(subroot.get("empName"));
subquery.where(subroot.get("empParentName").in(nameList));

query.where(baseRoot.get("empName").in(subquery));
query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(baseRoot.get("empName")));
List<Employee> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

As entities are not added, I'm assuming "empName" is variable name of emp_name column in employee and department class and empParentName for emp_parentName. nameList is the List of names you would like to filter on.